# mdframed even top and bottom margin for environments

Tags: spacing, environments, mdframed, framed

I'm trying to use LaTeX for my current ODE lecture and use `mdframed` for a "boxed proposition" to make it easier for the reader to distinguish the formulation from the proof.

This is what I use to create the boxed environment "proposition"

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{superlightred}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=superlightred]{proposition}{Satz}[chapter]
```

My problem is that this seems to include more spacing at the top of the proposition that at the bottom. Take a look here

[image]

The top contains almost one whole line of space, while the bottom seems a little narrow. How can I change this behaviour to even the spacing or even increase the bottom spacing?

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the spacing of your `proposition` environment with options passed in the first optional argument of `newmdtheoremenv`. Specifically, you can remove any inner margin by setting `innertopmargin` to 0, or to a negative value if needed. For more details, see the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) of `mdframed`.

It might be important to note that other lengths in a document may influence the behavior of `mdframed` environments' margins. The examples below show the influence of `parskip`, but I don't think it's the only length that influences.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\definecolor{superlightred}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=superlightred]{proposition}{Satz}[chapter]
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=superlightred,
                 innertopmargin=0pt]{notopmarginproposition}{Satz}[chapter]
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=superlightred,
                 innertopmargin=-2pt]{negativetopmarginproposition}{Satz}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\chapter{}

\begin{proposition}
Here is the proposition with default settings.
\end{proposition}

\begin{notopmarginproposition}
Here is the proposition with \textnormal{\texttt{innertopmargin=0pt}}.
\end{notopmarginproposition}

\begin{negativetopmarginproposition}
Here is the proposition with \textnormal{\texttt{innertopmargin=-2pt}}.
\end{negativetopmarginproposition}

\end{document}
```

With the code above, where `parskip` is set to 0, we get:
[image]
Using the same code, but changing `parskip` to `6pt`, we get:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but if I set `innerbottommargin = innertopmargin = 0pt` I still get more space at the top. Why is this the case? In your example you don't set the `innerbottommargin` (it defaults to 5px).

Comment: I know that other lengths influence how ``mdframed`` environments behave, so I'd say it's probably another length in your document. For example, if you change ``parskip``, the margins will change. But if you want the top margin to be decreased more than what it is when it is set to 0, you can always define a negative length for ``innertopmargin``.

Comment: I edited my answer to give some examples of how ``parskip`` influences the margins, but I think other lengths might have a similar behavior. I'm no expert, but in my experience, it's simpler to adjust the margins of ``mdframed`` environments at the end, when other lengths are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and discovered that the excess top margin disappeared if I removed the `amsthm` package from my preamble. I can't say that yours is caused by the same problem, but it could be something similar.